# Osmdroid always show marker description

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I'm working with Osmdroid, particularly with this class: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedOverlayWithFocus.java

It shows a ballon with text description when an item is tapped ('focused') but I want wo show the description of all items all the time.

Anybody had the dame issue yet of can perhaps give me a hint on what to change in the ItemizedOverlayWithFocus.java- class, probably the draw()- method to get that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that without changing anything in the library source code:

Use multiple `ItemizedOverlayWithFocus`, and in each one, put only one overlay item.